# Eclipse Juno: Windows "Open File" dialog box does not work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windows-7-x64, eclipse-juno

I recently move to Eclipse Juno from Indigo. Although Juno works perfectly as far as my needs the windows **"Open" dialog box** does not load for some reason. For example, File/Open File does not work.

This is a problem across all places where we need to include a file like adding external JARs or any other place where files need to be added from a windows directory. 
"Include Directory" does work where I need to get the directory included but the issue is only with file dialog box.

I have a Windows 7 64 bit and it’s a Eclipse with Java & CDT plug-in.
Reinstalling eclipse would be a last resort as I would need to re-configure 40+ projects again as we have a very peculiar setup here.

I did try to research this but hardly could find more details.. Any pointers to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Just wanted to add that tooltip does not work up when I hower mouse on the different icons/files ect, not sure if this is related but just wanted to mention.
Also, I tried updating my eclipse to Kepler but it still does not work, I am now wondering if my Windows 7 has something to do with this..?

Comment: I also wanted to add that I am sure the Dialog Box does not open at all, it is not like it opened the window but was minimized or hidden. I can confirm this as the focus to the eclipse main window is not lost.. :(

Comment: Check the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory for messages. Your project settings are stored in the workspace which an Eclipse reinstall will not change (but back it up!)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is written to log file when I hit File/Open File...
Do you know if there is a way of decreasing the log level so that most of the actions are logged, that way I might be able to find more details..

Comment: The log level can't be changed. There are some debug logs that can be enabled but they are only useful with a detailed knowledge of the relevant part of the source code.

Comment: (Yes its been a year, still no resolution) After some research, I think must not be eclipse but related to windows 7.. I upgraded eclipse to kepler but the issue didn't get resolved. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve this based on research done in this Eclipse [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349387). My work machine still has java 1.6.0_26 and this release has a bug related to AWT.

I changed the eclipse's java version to 1.6.0_45 and this issue was resolved. I used `-vm` parameter in [eclipse.ini file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) in to tell eclipse to use a different version.